# Magento resource model catalog product filter with attributes and category id

Tags: catalog, filter, catalogsearch

I am trying to develop custom filter navigation. Below is the code for product collection by category id

```
$category = Mage::getModel ('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                  // ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                  ->AddAttributeToSelect('name')
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                  ->addFinalPrice()
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('short_description')
                  ->addUrlRewrite()
                  ->AddCategoryFilter($category);


    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

    //$products->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' => '27')); /* here color attribute */
```

Product collection by category id is working as expected. But when i tried with single color attribute, it always returns an empty array. Same color 27 attribute gives one product as result when i check on default navigation.

What is the best way to achieve multiple attribute code filter with resource model catalog product collection?

Comment: frinds ask question brief i not understand

Comment: comment out this line `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);` to see if this is affecting.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri commented out but same result

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)->getProductCollection();
        $products
              ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
              ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
              ->addFinalPrice()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
              ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
              ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
              ->addAttributeToSelect('short_description')
              ->addUrlRewrite()

              //select color too
              ->addAttributeToSelect('color')
              ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                 array('attribute'=> 'color','eq' => '27')
                ))
              ;
```

Comment: I tried this,same result :(

Comment: Check my updated answer. Also if still doesn't work try with commenting out that visibility filter section as mentioned earlier.

Comment: tried all cases, but no result

Comment: I have diff approach now, try.

Comment: tried,not working boss

Comment: It is working in my testing site. Hope you have defined `$category_id` before my code.

Comment: Is `27` legit id for color? I doubt it's not.

Comment: yes it is like http://localhost/magento/women/new-arrivals.html?color=27 the value which magento used for category filter when user click some color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27627/discussion-between-mymotherland-and-adarsh-khatri).

Answer (score -1):

have check if the attribute has been set to yes ( display in frontend ) into BO and try this :

```
$products->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('in' => array('the color ids you picked separated by a comma')))
```